# Как в postgresql найти точно соответствие заданной строки?

Tags: postgresql

В обычном `sql` есть `REGEXP '\\\\bvalue\\\\b'`, он ищет точное соответствие в базе. Как написать аналог в `postgresql`?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
create table values(
  value text
);

insert into values values ('Lorem'), ('ipsum'), ('dolor'),('Lorem ipsum dolor');

select * 
  from values
  where value = 'ipsum';
  
select *
  from values
  where value ~ '\mipsum\M';
```

## результат

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 4
 value 
-------
 ipsum
(1 row)

       value       
-------------------
 ipsum
 Lorem ipsum dolor
(2 rows)
```

https://onecompiler.com/postgresql/3y7exvrvq

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP